# Performance investigation SSRS in VS2008

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Is there any way to investigate performance statistic for SSRS report from VS 2008 Shell.

I mean while generating preview for report see the statistic: How much time for rendering, how much time for query.

P.S. I know that WholeTime - TimeQueryExecutedSeparately = TimeRendering, but still I want to find a way.

Answer (score 0):

What's the point? Will your users use the VS 2008 Shell?

I would deploy to a test environment of Report Manager or SharePoint and run your reports there.  Then you can query the ReportServer.dbo.ExecutionLog3 view to get those statistics.